# Jenkins and Kubernetes Integration using with Helm

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I would like to integrate our Jenkins and Kubernetes clusters which works different servers.I have 2 cluster per `stage` and `production`. I already create a 2 name spaces on stage cluster to divide `development` and `stage`. I divide my values.yaml such as below.

- valeus.dev.yaml
- values.stage.yaml
- values.prod.yaml

So according to the GIT_BRANCH value; I would like to set namespace variable and deploy via `helm install` command. At this circumstances,

My question is, what is the best way to connect 2 cluster in Jenkinsfile for this condition cause for dev and test namespace I need to one cluster , for production I need to deploy another cluster.

```
 stage('deploy') {
   steps {
      script {
        if (env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/master") {
            def namepsace="dev"
            sh "helm upgrade --install -f values.dev.yaml --namespace ${namespace}"
        } else if (env.GIT_BRANCH =="origin/test"){
            def namepsace="stage"
            sh "helm upgrade --install -f values.stage.yaml --namespace ${namespace}"

        } else { 
            def namepsace="prod"
            sh "helm upgrade --install -f values.prod.yaml --namespace ${namespace}"
        }
```

Comment: It's a little pain to change helm k8s connection context, helm just use the same context as kubectl. You can find some discuss at https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4195.

Comment: I am also struggling to integrate Jenkins and k8s.. Before the change context I need to also make an integration between Jenkins and Kubernetes.. What is the best way to do this Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Are you using Helm version 2 or 3? Helm 3 has some improvements in this area (--kube-context)

Comment: Helm 3.. Do you have any example that I refer I could not find any

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will need to create the Jenkins secrets to add both kubeconfig files for your k8s Clusters, and in the if statement you load the kubeconfig for your environment

for example using your code above

```
stage('deploy') {
  steps {
    script {
      if (env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/master") {
        def namepsace="dev"
        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'kubeconfig-dev', variable: 'config')]) {
          sh """
          export KUBECONFIG=\${config}
          helm upgrade --install -f values.dev.yaml --namespace ${namespace}"
          """
        }
      } else if (env.GIT_BRANCH =="origin/test"){
        def namepsace="stage"
        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'kubeconfig-stage', variable: 'config')]) {
          sh """
          export KUBECONFIG=\${config}
          helm upgrade --install -f values.dev.yaml --namespace ${namespace}"
          """
        }
      } else {
        def namepsace="prod"
        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'kubeconfig-prod', variable: 'config')]) {
          sh """
          export KUBECONFIG=\${config}
          helm upgrade --install -f values.dev.yaml --namespace ${namespace}"
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I merged my kubeconfig files to the single config file which works my local pc properly .If I upload this config is that still works? I think I can create a secret for Kubernetes without any plugin am I correct?

Comment: Seems duplicate but due to this I guess I need to change context with namespace as well, can you also check this link context.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769890/store-kubernetes-cluster-credentials-in-jenkins-and-use-in-declarative-pipeline