# Store Kubernetes Cluster Credentials in Jenkins and use in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy k8s cluster using Helm 3 and jenkins. Jenkins and k8s running on different servers.I merged the kubeconfig files and I had all information in one config file ./kube directory. I would like to deploy my app to the related environment and namespace according to the GIT_BRANCH value. I have two question for below script.

1.What is the best way should I store k8s cluster credentials and will use in pipeline. I saw some plugins such as Kubernetes CLI but I can not be sure whether it will cover my requirement. If I use this plugin, should I store k8s file in to Jenkins machine manually or this plugin already handle this with uploading config file.

2.Should I change anything in below script to follow best practices?

```
         stage('Deploy to dev'){
         script{
             steps{
                 if(env.GIT_BRANCH.contains("dev")){

                        def namespace="dev"
                        def ENV="development"

                        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: ...)]) {
                        // change context with related namespace
                        sh "kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=${namespace}"

                        //Deploy with Helm
                        echo "Deploying"
                        sh "helm upgrade --install road-dashboard -f values.${ENV}.yaml --set tag=$TAG --namespace ${namespace}"    
                 }
             }
         }
     }

    stage('Deploy to Test'){
        script{
            steps{
                 if(env.GIT_BRANCH.contains("test")){

                        def namespace="test"
                        def ENV="test"

                        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: ...)]) {
                        // change context with related namespace
                        sh "kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=${namespace}"


                        //Deploy with Helm
                        echo "Deploying"
                        sh "helm upgrade --install road-dashboard -f values.${ENV}.yaml --set tag=$TAG --namespace ${namespace}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stage ('Deploy to Production'){

        when {
            anyOf{
                environment name: 'DEPLOY_TO_PROD' , value: 'true'
            }
        }

        steps{
            script{
                DEPLOY_PROD = false
                def namespace = "production"

                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'kube-config', variable: 'kubecfg')]){
                    //Change context with related namespace
                    sh "kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=${namespace}"

                    //Deploy with Helm
                    echo "Deploying to production"
                    sh "helm upgrade --install road-dashboard -f values.${ENV}.yaml --set tag=$TAG --namespace ${namespace}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this, but in theory the credentials variable is available as environment variable. Try to use `KUBECONFIG` as a variable name

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'secret', variable: 'KUBECONFIG')]) {

  // change context with related namespace
  sh "kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=${namespace}"

  //Deploy with Helm
  echo "Deploying"
  sh "helm upgrade --install road-dashboard -f values.${ENV}.yaml --set tag=$TAG --namespace ${namespace}"
}
```

Comment: Is there any special way to store the credentials file in the Jenkins system?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that worked for me:

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'k8s-dk-staging', variable: 'KUBECRED')]) {
   sh 'cat $KUBECRED > ~/.kube/config'
   sh './deploy-app.sh'
}
```

I don't like to do that, ideally I would like use *KUBECONFIG* but for now this is that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This an old post, worth updating with a newer response.

Using this Jenkins plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cli/

> Allows you to configure kubectl to interact with Kubernetes clusters from within your jobs. Any tool built on top of kubectl can then be used from your pipelines to perform deployments, e.g. Shopify/krane or Helm.

```
// Example when used in a pipeline
node {
  stage('Apply Kubernetes files') {
    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'user1', serverUrl: 'https://api.k8s.my-company.com']) {
      sh 'kubectl apply -f my-kubernetes-directory'
    }
  }
}
```